# Passing a Generic Object and deciding what to populate in the <asp:Label>

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, generic-list

I have an `<asp:Label>`  I wish to populate depending on the Generic object that I pass to it.

At the moment I have the following code:-

```
    private void PopulateEnglishQuestion(int questionId)
    {
        ReportQuestion reportQuestion = questionsBll.GetReportQuestions().Where(x=> x.ReportQuestionId == questionId).FirstOrDefault();
        PopulateLabels(reportQuestion);
    }

    private void PopulateTranslatedQuesiton(int questionId)
    {
        ReportQuestionTranslation reportQuestionTranslation = questionsBll.GetReportQuestionsTranslation().Where(x => x.QuestionId == questionId).FirstOrDefault();
        PopulateLabels(reportQuestionTranslation);
    }

    private void PopulateLabels<T>(T item)
    {
        lblQuestionTitle.Text = typeof (T) == typeof (ReportQuestion)
                                    ? ((ReportQuestion) (item)).ReportQuestionTitle
                                    : ((ReportQuestionTranslation) (item)).ReportQuestionTitleTrans; 
    }
```

How can I get the method PopulateLabels to work properly?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with your `PopulateLabels` method now?

Comment: Everyone's saying use an interface but every class inherits from object and implements ToString. What's wrong with overriding and using ToString()?

Comment: @StephenKennedy - What if he has to put the question here, but somewhere else he has to put the answer from the same object.  Should the ToString be the question or the answer?  If you implement an interface, you can have both...with ToString() you can only have one use for the class.  Interfaces create more flexible design.

Comment: @StephenKennedy how to override and put ToString(?  ReportQuestion and ReportQuestionTranslation have different fields, so I cannot implement an interface no?

Comment: @StephenKennedy is there any other way rather than using an Interface?  I do not wish to change pre-existing code

Comment: Yes, you can implement an interface with a title text string - e.g. csharpler's answer - or, if you bear in mind Kevin's caveats you could override ToString in each class.

Comment: Either way would require changing the classes. The text is coming from ReportQuestionTranslation.ReportQuestionTitleTrans or ReportQuestion.ReportQuestionTitle, is that right?

Comment: yes that is correct.  Anther way would be to do an if-else and check the culture, or a switch

Comment: I've put an answer in about how to override ToString(). You then simply call ToString() on the object irrespective of type. This will of course compile because of inheritance from object.ToString(). HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `interface`.

```
public interface IQuestion
{
    string Title { get; }
}

public class ReportQuestion : IQuestion
{
    public string Title { get { return ReportQuestionTitle; } }
}

public class ReportQuestionTranslation: IQuestion
{
    public string Title { get { return ReportQuestionTitleTrans; } }
}

private void PopulateLabels(IQuestion item)
{
    lblQuestionTitle.Text = item.Title;
}
```

Or use method overloading:

```
public void PopulateTitle(ReportQuestion question)
{
    lblQuestionTitle.Text = question.ReportQuestionTitle;
}

public void PopulateTitle(ReportQuestionTranslation question)
{
    lblQuestionTitle.Text = question.ReportQuestionTitleTrans;
}
```

Unrecommended:

```
public class QuestionTitleFormatter
{
    public string GetTitle(object question)
    {
        if(question is ReportQuestion)
            return ((ReportQuestion)question).ReportQuestionTitle;

        if(question is ReportQuestionTranslation)
            return ((ReportQuestionTranslation)question).ReportQuestionTitleTrans;

        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("{0} is not supported", questionType.Name);
    }
}

public void PopulateTitle(object question)
{
    var formatter = new QuestionTitleFormatter();
    lblQuestionTitle.Text = formatter.GetTitle(question);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other method than using an interface?  I have to change some pre-existing code if I have to implement an interface.  Can't I do it with types?

Comment: Interfaces are the recommended way to create a clean hierarchy. If you're not concerned with best practices then you could just use the types. Generics aren't necessary at that point since there's nothing to create a relationship between the classes.

Comment: Yes I agree that Interfaces are the way to go, however I do not want to change any pre-existing classes.  The other way would be to do a simple switch statement

Comment: I already posted an edit. You'll either need to use reflection to determine the types or simply have a different method for each type.

Comment: Thanks Romoku, I will check if I can change any pre-existing code to implement the class example

Answer (score 5):

You should use an interface both `ReportQuestion` and `ReportQuestionTranslation` implement:

```
interface IQuestion
{
    string TitleText;
}
```

Then, use the following code:

```
public void PopulateLabels(IQuestion item)
{
    lblQuestionTitle.Text = item.TitleText;
}
```

Comment: `public void PopulateLabels(IQuestion question)`

Comment: @csharpler how can I have an interface if ReportQuestion and ReportQuestion translated have different fields?

Comment: You have to implement the interface in each class, returning the relevant property or field or variable for that particular class.

Answer (score 1):

The ToString() approach would be something like this:

```
class ReportQuestion {
    public override string ToString() { return ReportQuestionTitle; }
    ...
}

class ReportQuestionTranslation{
    public override string ToString() { return ReportQuestionTitleTrans; }
    ...
}
```

assuming that I answered my own question correctly in the comment above asking where the string will come from.

Comment: He said that he doesn't want to change the pre-existing code which smells.

Comment: Yep, I saw that, but he was pressing me for more info on the ToString() route and I'm happy to help. If this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, yes this will have to change the class still.  I will check if I can change any pre-existing classes because the Interface example is much more standard I agree.

Comment: The more I look at it the more inclined I too would be to go with an interface or abstract (base) class as conceptually a Report Question Translation "is a" Report Question. This approach is however a touch simpler. Either way good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help Stephen, yes I do agree that both classes should implement a question interface. Will see what approach I can implement.

Answer (score 0):

You could just override ToString() on those objects and not worry about any transformations or types in PopulateLabel.

Comment: In the definition of each relevant class, add the method public override string ToString() - see StephenKennedy's answer below for more detail.